# Why another machine does not boot on the same disk with EFI and Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have an external hard disk containing an EFI system partition, a Ubuntu 20.10 partition and some other partitions, including Mac OS X, so it works as dual boot.

I have two Macbook Pros: v 5,5 Intel Core 2 Duo RAM 8G year 2009 and v8,1 Intel Core i5 RAM 16G year 2011.  Any of them can run the same binaries and Mac OS X El Capitan.

When it comes to Ubuntu, both machines begin similarly: in the firmware menu, I select the hard disk EFI system partition, then appear the GRUB menu, the long list of messages, including the Ubuntu 20.10 welcome.

However, the older machine fails on

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/71E2-6200
```

See the photograph: [image: attached photograph]

71E2-6200 is the UUID of the EFI system partition.

I also see this a few lines down:

```
[  103.625925] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6368 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x8
```

where the sector number can change.

Running `fsck` on the EFI system partition and Ubuntu partition shows no problem.

Do you have any idea why the older machine fails whereas the newer succeeds?

Information obtained (after booting on the newer machine):

```
mac2011-linux% cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=1ce2a9e1-0d15-4c20-9f53-32fc9c47b525 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=71E2-6200  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
# for NFS
/home/alba    /export/alba   none    bind  0  0
# /dev/disk/by-label/EFI /mnt/EFI auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
#UUID=71E2-6200  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=71E2-6200  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
UUID=71E2-6200  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
mac2011-linux% sudo blkid
[sudo] password for alba: 
/dev/sdb4: LABEL="Ubuntu backup" UUID="1ce2a9e1-0d15-4c20-9f53-32fc9c47b525" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Ubuntu backup" PARTUUID="98872d9f-9d11-4c9e-8acb-fb1d0c0ccb9a"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="05bdacf6-78ff-451d-8c4d-bb812fd68e83"
/dev/sda2: UUID="0492d65c-8b14-356a-9d3d-337f44e8d58a" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" LABEL="SSD 1T" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="MacOS_El_Capitan" PARTUUID="10b29023-d982-4be8-8ceb-226c04893a8b"
/dev/sda3: UUID="87867aee-1d5c-3c9e-ae36-8d2df5c162f1" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" LABEL="Recovery HD" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="Recovery HD" PARTUUID="895fd6af-7b68-4873-bec1-6dc154aece4f"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="dc68435c-f80c-4beb-a09b-69015ad516e6" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Ubuntu" PARTUUID="4c1d9c0a-978e-46fd-9ae0-b49c6ed27037"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="71E2-6200" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="2c99fbe4-96f8-465b-b528-d03c40083bd7"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="e490c4f5-2f3d-3996-8db7-6e45050c8636" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" LABEL="El Capitan" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="HGST 1 TB" PARTUUID="1a198393-f3db-4c36-bfed-7a07e4c43520"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="47af6fd5-545e-3b2b-a9f9-f537efe3354b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" LABEL="Recovery HD" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="Recovery HD" PARTUUID="d00d1e40-ec70-4cc7-a97a-3f29a763011e"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
```

I have the outputs of `journalctl` in the booting and non booting cases.

Notable lines in the non booting case :

```
Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux kernel: ACPI: BIOS bug: multiple APIC/MADT found, using 0

Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux kernel: PCI: MMCONFIG for 0000 [bus00-3f] at [mem 0xf0000000-0xf3ffffff] (base 0xf0000000) (size reduced!)
Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux kernel: PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug

Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux kernel: tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to clocksource watchdog
Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux kernel: TSC found unstable after boot, most likely due to broken BIOS. Use 'tsc=unstable'.
Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux kernel: sched_clock: Marking unstable (1164224651, 840043)<-(1171542672, -6477987)

Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux kernel: Unstable clock detected, switching default tracing clock to "global"
                                      If you want to keep using the local clock, then add:
                                        "trace_clock=local"
                                      on the kernel command line

Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux blkmapd[290]: open pipe file /run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/blocklayout failed: No such file or directory
```

`blkmapd` is related to NFS. The `blkmapd` is also is the log of the booting case so it can't cause non booting.  Same for `use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug`.

Older machine:

```
Apr 24 19:38:28 mac2011-linux kernel: DMI: Apple Inc. MacBookPro5,5/Mac-F2268AC8, BIOS    MBP55.88Z.00AC.B03.0906151708 06/15/09
```

`00AC.B03` is up to date.

Newer machine:

```
Apr 24 19:42:40 mac2011-linux kernel: DMI: Apple Inc. MacBookPro8,1/Mac-94245B3640C91C81, BIOS    MBP81.88Z.0050.B00.1804101331 04/10/18
```

The Ubuntu 20.04LTS live installer works on the older machine USB.  This shows that the older machine is compatible with Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

I have a SSD clone of the hard disk.  The SSD clone behaves similarly, although some boot messages are different.  This shows that the cause of the problem is not a dying disk.

Any more idea?

Comment: Can you add the `/etc/fstab` and the output of `sudo blkid` to the question please? And copy and paste the text please, do not add a screenshot.

Comment: Done.  Not that booting succeeds with same disk and different machine.

Comment: I don't see the `sudo blkid` output for the UEFI partition.  Please show the full output of `sudo blkid` showing all partitions with their UUIDs.

Comment: Done. Sorry.  I also have the outputs of `journalctl -b`, I am trying to extract the most interesting parts.

Comment: You have 2 UEFI partitions with different UUIDs.  If I were experiencing this problem the first thing I'd do is change the UUID in `fstab`. The installer tends to ignore new UEFI partitions you make and installs grub in the first one it finds.

Comment: I have two EFI system partitions because the disk in question (sdb) is now mounted besides another running installation disk (sda).  The root UUID in sdb /etc/fstab is 1ce2a9e1-0d15-4c20-9f53-32fc9c47b525, consistent with the output of blkid for /dev/sdb4.  There can be no error as it is booting on a different machine.

Comment: "there can be no error " ??? Best wishes fixing this .... error.

Comment: OK I am going to reboot on this disk alone and refill the blkid output so it is more clear.

Comment: Done.  Now it is clear.

Comment: Agreed.  That is why I use UUIDs.  But we should concentrate on this fact: it is booting on another machine.  I am adding information in my question.

Comment: I will change the title accordingly.

Comment: Check your bootable disk, make sure that it is written correctly.

Another thing: Check your computer's BIOS settings. Make sure that your BIOS supports booting from more than one machine and UUID and stuff.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have done with some success.  The older machine cannot boot Ubuntu if more than one device is present but I am quite sure it can boot MacOS if more than one device present (I am going to check) so I think something is wrong in the Ubuntu setup.

Comment: Confirmed.  This Macbook pro 5,5 can boot Mac OS X even if more than one Mac OS X device is present, but cannot boot Ubuntu if more that one Ubuntu device is present.

Answer (score 1):

For starting the older machine with Ubuntu 20.04LTS on USB, I used a micro SD card in a USB card reader.  I could not see it in the Mac boot menu, until I disconnected the internal SSD.

I also routinely modified a few files of the external hard disk (that I use for backup) and tried again to boot on the newer machine. It only worked after running fsck manually.[image]

I tried again to start the older machine on the external hard disk, still with its internal SSD disconnected, and it worked.  After reconnecting the internal SSD, it did not work.

> I have a SSD clone of the hard disk. The SSD clone behaves similarly,
> although some boot messages are different. This shows that the cause
> of the problem is not a dying disk.

I have tried again with the clone and the behavior is identical.  This confirms that the file system corruption is just an incident.

So all this boils down to the fact that **the older machine Macbook pro 5,5 needs the internal device to be disconnected while the newer does not**.

In Ubuntu `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, GRUB is always configured to look for `hd0` whatever the real starting device number is (and it is normally >= 1).  I have tried to replace `hd0` by `hd1` (as is already in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`) but this does not help.

No more recent firmware is available for the Macbook pro 5,5.